# R function to calculate the p-value

Tags: r, p-value

For a dataset with mean = 67 and the standard deviation = 6, how could I find the p-value associated with the true population mean being 79 OR greater in R?

Comment: you also need the sample size

Comment: In R, it would be `pnorm(79, mean = 67, sd = 6/sqrt(n), lower.tail = FALSE)` (where `n` is the sample size)

Comment: The original post says that the *dataset* had sd 6, not that the population sd was 6. It's important to be aware that the uncertainty in estimation of $\sigma$ by $s$ has an impact unless the sample size is sufficiently large.